# How to get type and generic type from javax.lang.model.VariableElement?

Tags: java, generics, annotation-processing, javapoet

I'm using annotation processing and javapoet library to generate some source code.

Say, I've a

```
VariableElement fieldElement
```

and if

```
System.out.println("type:- " + fieldElement.asType().toString());
```

prints

> type:- java.util.Set<com.example.demo.test.model.User>

How do I get the Set class and User class so I can do something like this with javapoet?

```
ClassName user = ClassName.get("com.example.demo.test.model", "User");
ClassName set = ClassName.get("java.util", "Set");
TypeName setOfUsers = ParameterizedTypeName.get(set, user);
```

Some string comparison would get the job done, but doesn't seem like the ideal approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below code.

For getting that User class you can use **`fieldElement.getEnclosingElement()`**, it will give you class name with full package name.

Now if you want only name of that class you can use **`enclosingElement.getSimpleName()`**.

And to get enclosedByElement you can use [TypeSymbol](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.kohsuke.sorcerer/sorcerer-javac/latest/com/sun/tools/javac/code/Symbol.TypeSymbol.html).Simply cast fieldElement.asType() to **`Type`** and get **`tsym`** attribute.

```
        VariableElement fieldElement;

        Symbol.TypeSymbol containerForEnclosingElement=((Type)fieldElement.asType()).tsym;
        Element enclosingElement=fieldElement.getEnclosingElement();

        System.out.println("containerForEnclosingElement:- " +  containerForEnclosingElement);
        System.out.println("enclosingElement:- " +  enclosingElement);
        System.out.println("enclosingElement Name:- " +  enclosingElement.getSimpleName());
        System.out.println("fieldElement without root Type:- "+((Type) fieldElement.asType()).getTypeArguments().get(0));
```

Above code will print output as below.

```
containerForEnclosingElement:- java.util.Set
enclosingElement:- com.example.demo.test.model.User.
enclosingElement Name:- User
fieldElement without root Type:- com.example.demo.test.model.User
```

You can also create one Utility method to get this two values.

This will help you.

Comment: fieldElement.getEnclosingElement() is not giving User. I've `Set<User> users` as a private variable in another class. It is giving me the another class. Also, from what package does `Symbol.TypeSymbol` come from?

Comment: `import com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol;` You can import this.

Comment: If you see my next line `fieldElement.getEnclosingElement().getSimpleName()`, you will get idea.

Comment: as I said `fieldElement.getEnclosingElement().getSimpleName()` is also returning the name of the class in which `Set<User> users` is a private field. And getting cannot resolve symbol .tsym after importing com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol;

Comment: I've teamviewer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219915/discussion-between-sagar-gangwal-and-drunken-daddy).